# Should I use an ObservableCollection for Images

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

I am using a mvvm pattern for an application that sources its data from a sql ce database using the Entity Framework version 4. The WPF application only has one view (don't need anymore as the app is not that big). I am displaying a collection of properties from the database in a listbox, by creating an observablecollection in my viewmodel and binding this. This works exactly as expected. The issue is that I now have another listbox (in the same view) that needs to be populated with Images for each property. To be clear, each property has a bunch of images, but each image is only assigned to one property.

What would be the best way to display the images, I thought maybe creating another observablecollection for the images, but I am not sure how I would then ensure that only images for the appropriate property are shown. Or should I simply bind the listbox to the Images property of each property (house)?

Cheers

```
    private void Load()
    {
        PropertyList = new ObservableCollection<Property>((from property in entities.Properties.Include("Images")
                                                          select property));
        propertyView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PropertyList);
        if (propertyView != null)
            propertyView.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(propertyView_CurrentChanged);           

        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentContact");
        RaisePropertyChanged("SaleTitle");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Address");
        RaisePropertyChanged("AuctioneerName");
        RaisePropertyChanged("AgentName");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Price");
        RaisePropertyChanged("NextBid");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds distinctly like a different responsibility (a master/details view).  In the true spirit of MVVM I'd create a new View and a new ViewModel - perhaps:

```
PropertyImagesViewModel
    - public Property Property { get; set; }
    - public IList<Image> Images { get; set; }
    - public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }

PropertyImagesView
```

Don't forgot to call RaisePropertyChanged() in each of the property setters

Also note that ObservableCollection does nothing if you aren't manipulating the contents one-at-a-time.  If all do you is update the entire collection all-at-once, then it gives you no tangible benefit.

Another thing - if you need to notify that all your properties changed:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(null);
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I think I do need to use an observable collection, but do correct me if I am wrong. My program needs to be able to delete, add, and drag n drop individual images. Only the images for the appropriate property should display in this box. Where I am finding difficult implementing this, is when I have already added and assigned my image to a property object in the observable collection (which can then be saved to the database). I know I could just display it by binding the listbox to a list of images, but I need to be able to check which image is currently selected, to be able to remove it etc.

Comment: See edit.  In your case, since you'd be adding/removing images individually, you are correct - you need to use ObservableCollection.  To track which image is selected, I've added a SelectedIndex property to the ViewModel.  You can bind this to (for example) a WPF ListBox's SelectedIndex property to track which one is currently selected.